# use name of war file deployed dynamically in standalone.xml or domain.xml

Tags: java, jboss, java-8, jboss-eap-7

I'm configuring kyecloak authentication for my application which runs on JBoss EAP 7. In this configuration, I need to add below subsystem to profile in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
        <secure-deployment name="myApp-1.0.1.war">
            <realm>appRealm</realm>
            <resource>relam-resource</resource>
            <bearer-only>true</bearer-only>
            <enable-basic-auth>true</enable-basic-auth>
            <realm-public-key>somekey</realm-public-key>
            <auth-server-url>http://localhost:9080/auth</auth-server-url>
            <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
            <credential name="secret">secret-key</credential>
        </secure-deployment>
    </subsystem>
```

In this, it needs the name of war file which will be having version number getting changed for each deployment. I don't want to deploy war by removing the number from it's name.

Is  there any way by which I can use the name of deployed war file as a variable like:

```
<secure-deployment name="${deployment.deplyedFileName}">
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using below configuration:
 `--<secure-deployment name="WAR MODULE NAME.war">`
 The secure-deployment name attribute identifies the WAR you want to secure. Its value is the `module-name` defined in web.xml with .war appended.In this case you have to make sure that module-name is changed every time per web.xml/war.
As mentioned in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/jboss-adapter.html

Comment: Yes & that is the question if we can use any variable which can used rather hard-coding war name. e.g. jboss.server.config.dir points to "JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration"

Comment: If you go through above documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/jboss-adapter.html and try out using WAR MODULE NAME.war and tell me what happens,it would be easier to help